# PHP Datetime comparison Makes no sense

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am comparing dates in PHP for some reason its now working properly. I want to echo red font if the date is passed or equal to current date. I know there are other questions on this and I read lots of those, but it just does not make sense to me.

Two variables:

```
$Now = new DateTime('now');
$DueDate = new DateTime($pScheduledDueDate);
```

When echoed:

```
echo $DueDate->format('m/d/y').'<br/>';
echo $Now->format('m/d/y').'<br/>';
```

Returns:

```
11/27/14
01/21/16
```

Comparing:

```
 if($DueDate->format('m/d/y') <= $Now->format('m/d/y')){
    echo '<font color="red">'.$DueDate->format('m/d/y').'</font>';
 }
 else {
    echo $DueDate->format('m/d/y');
 }


Result: false. It does not make sense to me. Shouldn't it return true?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing two strings to eachother, which won't necessarily make sense, because PHP won't know that they're dates and should be compared as dates.

To compare two DateTime objects like that, I would change your comparison method to look at the DateTime's timestamp value instead:

```
if($DueDate->getTimestamp() <= $Now->getTimestamp())
```

This compares the integer time value of the two DateTime objects, and you'll get the expected results.

PHP DateTime objects can also be compared directly, without the need to involve reformatting

```
if($DueDate <= $Now)
```

Comment: You got the answer because better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's happening, is because when you use `format`, it transforms your DateTime into a string. The correct way to you compare is like that:

```
$Now = new DateTime('now');
$pScheduledDueDate = '11/27/14';
$DueDate = new DateTime($pScheduledDueDate);
if($DueDate <= $Now)...
```

And for "echoing" you can format the way you want to, look here an example: https://ideone.com/dgSVDY